# Android create a new folder on internal "Device Storage"

Tags: android

So, I am creating an app that will be saving pictures.  But I'd like to bundle all of the pictures into an easy-to-get-to folder on the main "device storage" directory.

I'd like to save to an external card, but the device I'm testing on does not have one and other devices will possibly not have them either (Eventually, I'll allow the app user to decide if they want internal or external memory).

Right now, I was trying to find the folder like this:

```
String directory = "/mnt/CPB";
File mainFolder = new File(directory);
if(mainFolder.exists() && mainFolder.isDirectory()){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CPB Is Made", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CPB does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mainFolder.mkdir();
}
```

This is obviously not working.  So where do I go from here?

I'd like the folder to show up on the main directory view when viewing folders or when attaching to a computer to view the directories.  Also, Do I need any type of permissions in the android manifest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I'd like to bundle all of the pictures into an easy-to-get-to folder on the main "device storage" directory.

I am going to assume, from context, that you are referring to what the Android SDK calls [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

Note that while you may think that cluttering up the user's external storage with yet another top-level directory is a good idea, please do not be shocked if users disagree with your assessment.

> Eventually, I'll allow the app user to decide if they want internal or external memory

My guess is that you are referring to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) and [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html), respectively.

> I was trying to find the folder like this:

You do not have read/write access to `/mnt`, and the user has no access to that either.

What you appear to be aiming for is `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. However, you should strongly consider either `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` (for common locations, like photos and stuff) or `getExternalFilesDir()` on `Context` (for an app-specific location on external storage).

> Do I need any type of permissions in the android manifest?

All locations on external storage require `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` on Android 4.3 and older. Also, the locations on external storage provided by `Environment` require `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` on Android 4.4+ as well.

However, if you use `getExternalFilesDir()`, you do not need `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` on Android 4.4+. This is another reason to consider using that location.

Also note that `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is a `dangerous` permission in Android 6.0+, meaning that if your `targetSdkVersion` is 23+, you have to ask for it at runtime. Plus, regardless of `targetSdkVersion`, the user can decide to not grant you that permission. Hence, avoiding `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is generally a good idea.

Comment: Wow, this is the best information I've received in a long time.  You really explained what I needed and am looking for!  Also, you make a good point.  I assumed incorrectly that most people would be looking for the images in a folder-view type setting

Answer (score 1):

main device storage is not `/mnt`, it's usually `/storage/sdcard0` (at least on my nexus 4)

better yet, use [`getExternalStorageDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29)

Comment: so, what I've been reading is that [`getExternalStorageDirectory()`][1] will make a folder in external memory, but if there is no external memory, it will make it on internal?


  [1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29

Comment: From the same page:  _Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory can better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that can hold a relatively large amount of data and that is shared across all applications (does not enforce permissions). Traditionally this is an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be mounted as a filesystem on a computer._